# EPPlus Load CSV and Format All Cells as Text

Tags: .net, excel, epplus

I am trying to import a CSV and have all cells show exactly how they were sent in via the CSV. Everything actually works great with the converting of the csv to the excel file and I email the attachment only to see that the data in some columns is messed up. For example I have a date in a cell that is of format mm/dd/yyyy and it shows when I load the file in excel as an integer. There are other cells throughout that also have this same issue. I can't format every cell individually because I'm loading a bunch of cells of various types so I was hoping I could basically just tell the excel file to just take what is sent in and display exactly that.

It is my understanding that changing the format to "@" should do what I'm looking for, however that is not what I am seeing.

While testing with a cell that I know is a date I tried the following and didn't see any change.

```
worksheet.Cells["B1"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
```

However if I specify the formatting as this it works. The issue like I said above though is I have other cells throughout that I don't know if they're dates or where they are that I need formatted.

```
worksheet.Cells["B1"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
```

I also tried something like this and it didn't work:

```
worksheet.Cells["A:XFD"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
```

Here is my full text example:

```
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var p = new ExcelPackage(outputStream))
    {
        var format = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelTextFormat();
        format.Delimiter = '|';
        format.DataTypes = new[] { eDataTypes.String };

        foreach (var page in fileContent)
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(page.Key);

            worksheet.Cells.LoadFromText(page.Value, format);

            worksheet.Cells["A:XFD"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
            worksheet.Cells["B1"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy"; //this works but not when I change it to "@"
            worksheet.Cells["MR11"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Cells["MS11"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
            //worksheet.Cells["A:XFD"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
            //worksheet.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
            //worksheet.Column(2).Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
        }
        p.Save();
    }
```

So is my understanding of how the "@" symbol should work incorrect? I don't think the datatype should be an issue since I am using a CSV which is just one big string.

Comment: If you don´t want to modify anything, just import the CSV as text, not as general. To your eyes, it will seem the same, but it is not.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego when you say to import as text and not general how would you do that? Not sure I understand what different I would have to do based on my code above.

Comment: You are trying to import one CSV to Excel, aren't you? So just, change the extension from CSV to TXT, or just open as txt file. Once Excel assistant begin, then  choose Data Type as Text, not General, and done.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego I think I see the issue in what you are saying. The problem is that the EPPlus extension which I am using is generating the excel file from the csv and emailing it out. So I need the excel file it generates to be of the proper format since it won't always be going to me. I believe you are just saying to change how I would open a csv if I was opening it directly in excel.

Comment: Might help if you post a few lines of your CSV file as an example.  Keep in mind that in Excel, generally, you can have strings or doubles as values.  Dates, for examples are double - the integer part is the day and the decimal is the time.  But if you tell epplus to treat everything as a string that it will store it in excel like that.

Comment: @ErnieS that is exactly what I was trying to do, was to tell using the "@" that it is text. Is that the correct way to do that? I was trying to get it to see all cells as that format. Some of my values getting sent in are for example "10/25/2019" which was getting switched to an int and also some values that were "1,3" that was getting converted to something. So I just want everything sent in to be seen as a string to and to be rendered in the exact way it is in the csv since it is actually a string there.

Comment: I basically have no way of knowing what could be input by a user, this is actually a dump of user's responses, so I just want exactly what they put in to be shown in the excel.

Answer (score 1):

I found a hack to get this at least functional in my code. I basically count the columns and have to create the DataTypes array in a for loop. So if I have 600 columns I need to add the eDataTypes.String 600 times to the formatter. It isn't pretty but for some reason the "@" won't work for me to get things formatted as text.

```
var format = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelTextFormat();
format.Delimiter = '|';
            
List<eDataTypes> allTypes = new List<eDataTypes>();
for(int i = 0;i < columnCount; i++)
{
    allTypes.Add(eDataTypes.String);
}

format.DataTypes = allTypes.ToArray();
```